# Openpyxl write in boxes in cell format

Tags: formatting, cell, openpyxl, numeric

I have difficulty creating an excel table with numerical data extrapolated with web scraping, the data are always transcribed in text format and I can not add them, some ideas

```
            def excel():
                
                # Writing on a EXCEL FILE
                filename = (f"{myPath}/Monatsplan {userfinder} {month} {year}.xlsx")
                dienstorinfo = string1
                emptycell = ' '   
                x = len(dienstorinfo)
                if x == 0:
                    dienstorinfo = tagesinfo2
                try:
                    wb = load_workbook(filename)
                    ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # select first worksheet
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    headers_row = ['Datum','Dienst','Funktion','Von','Bis','Schichtdauer','Bezahlte Zeit','Überzeit','Sonnats Zulage','Nachtdienst']
                    wb = Workbook()
                    ws = wb.active
                wb.save(filename)
                ws.append([soup_datum,dienstorinfo,soup_funktion,soup_dienstbegin,soup_dienstende,soup_schichtdauer,soup_bezahltezeit,emptycell,emptycell,emptycell,emptycell,emptycell])

                for cols in ws.iter_cols(  ):
                     if cols[-1].value:
                        cols[-1].border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'),right=Side(style='thin'),top=Side(style='thin'),bottom=Side(style='thin'))                                
                wb.save(filename)
                wb.close()
            excel()
```

Comment: By text format you mean they are written into excel as strings? You can fix that by changing them to a int or float before writing into Excel

Comment: I can't convert the string to integer because these are values that contain hours (09:15) so if I do it returns me error, even if I remove the : and replace them with a., I no longer correspond to the schedules in the sense that I would like to add them at the end...

Comment: Then you can convert them to datetimes.